# Memoizing traversed fs paths with Node.js

Tags: node.js, hash, hashmap, hashtable, memoization

I have a tool that is doing concurrent searches through a filesystem for certain files. As the tool searches through the fs, it may find that it needs to search in directories not originally included in the search.

What I should do is memoize each directory that has already started to be searched.

I can't think of a better way to memoize file paths except to store them in a hash like this:

```
interface IMemoizationMap {
  [key: string]: boolean
}
```

so that might look like:

```
const hash = {
  '/Users/you/projects/x': true,
  '/Users/you/projects/x/lib': true,
  '/Users/you/projects/x/lib': true,
  ...
  ...
  '/Users/you/some-stuff/z': true
};
```

Then I do a quick lookup to see if I need to search a certain directory. What feels awkward about this solution is that the values in the hash could pretty much be anything - true, false, undefined.

Is this the best way to memoize traversed filepaths?

As an aside, is the performance of

```
key in hash
```

the same as

```
hash[key]
```

?

If that is the case, then there would be some worth to data stored as the value:

When a directory starts being searched I could make the value false, and then when the directory finishes searching I could flip the value to true. Then the value at least means *something*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go with `Map`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

> The Map object holds key-value pairs. Any value (both objects and
>   primitive values) may be used as either a key or a value.

Or `Set`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

> The Set object lets you store unique values of any type, whether
>   primitive values or object references.

I would choose `Set`, but i'm unaware of performance comparisons between both when testing if the value exists already on the collection.